# Seprarate data in column without adding new column

Tags: r, data-cleaning, csv

I'm scraping data from a PDFs I have saved locally (if I can find the link to one of the problem PDFs, I update this post), and i'm running into an issue.  I've set the code up so that it will read data into a new column if there are 2 spaces between words, strings, whatever.  some of the data isn't spaced very well on the csv, so it will read a cell in as `|1 100%|` instead of `|1|100%|` as an example.  I've done this because some of the columns will contain a sentence, so I need to keep those together

What I'd like to do, becasue this keeps happening SOMEWHAT randomly (random in terms of the PDF, not random within the PDFs) with a few PDFs is to figure out some new code that will simply separate those columns based on the space, and push everything in that row right one cell.  Example code below.  Note that it always happens in the same column, as shown in the sample data.

Everything I've tried has just resulted in additional columns, which also throws off the data.

```
current_df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                         X2 = c("a 100", "b", "c", "d 400", "e"),
                         X3 = c("aa", 200, 300, "dd", 500),
                         X4= c("dog", "bb", "cc", "chair", "ee"),
                         X5 = c("", "lamp", "desk", "", "speaker"))





goal_df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 X2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 X3 = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
                 X4 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"),
                 X5 = c("dog", "lamp", "desk", "chair", "speaker"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clumsy solution:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(t(
  apply(as.matrix(current_df), 1, function(r) {
    out <- unlist(strsplit(r, "\\s+"))
    out <- out[!is.na(out) & nzchar(out)]
    stopifnot(length(out) == length(r))
    out
  }))
), names(current_df))
#   X1 X2  X3 X4      X5
# 1  1  a 100 aa     dog
# 2  2  b 200 bb    lamp
# 3  3  c 300 cc    desk
# 4  4  d 400 dd   chair
# 5  5  e 500 ee speaker
```

You will want to review the columns' `class`es, since moving strings around tends to disrupt numbers. I ignored numbers/strings here and just converted everything to `character` in the first `as.matrix` step, assuming that since you're parsing a PDF, you likely have to police that portion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `apply` + `strsplit` + `type.convert` like below

```
type.convert(
  data.frame(
    t(apply(
      current_df,
      1,
      function(v) unlist(strsplit(v, "\\s+"))
    ))
  ),
  as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
  X1 X2  X3 X4      X5
1  1  a 100 aa     dog
2  2  b 200 bb    lamp
3  3  c 300 cc    desk
4  4  d 400 dd   chair
5  5  e 500 ee speaker
```